# Looping through selected cells to indent text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following Google Spreadsheet script that attempts to loop through all selected cells and then update the value so that it adds an indent, by adding

```
=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + value[row] + '")
```

around the value.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function indentText() {
  var values = ss.getActiveRange().getValues();
  var newValues = new Array();

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != '') {
      newValues.push(['=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + values[i][0] + '")']);
    } else {
      newValues.push(['']);  
    }
  }

  ss.getActiveRange().setValues(newValues);

};

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Indent Text",
    functionName : "indentText"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Indent Text", entries);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question,

there is clearly a lack in the Google Script API to indent cells..

Still, I find the `CONCAT` approach ugly, if one wants to indent 2 times, the formula will be:

```
=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"'Hello World'")")
```

Which is ugly, I would simply pre-calculate the prefix and concatenate in the script and not let the formula do the work. This will also make un-indenting much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a better way to accomplish this, but I can offer a few notes.

- I like that you declared `ss` at a global scope, but `ss` isn't a very good variable name. Even if it is what Google uses in their API documentation.
- I tend to avoid using `!=` in an `If` if I'm taking action on `==` as well.
- It might seem silly, but it makes sense to define an empty string "constant". It's difficult at a glance to tell if if this is space or an empty string. Don't trade a few keystrokes for readability.
- You're inconsistent in which type of quotes you're using. You switched from single quotes in `indentText()` to double quotes in `onOpen()`.